# How long will programmatically registered broadcast receiver live?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to implement feature in my Android application which will allow user to receive notification when their country is supported in my application and I have some doubts how to implement this feature.

**Use case scenario looks like this**:

User goes to Activity where he can see the list of supported countries. User's country is always first and if it's not supported there is a button where he can click and request to be informed when his country become supported.

**Some of ideas**:

**1.** When user click on a button I'll register network state changed broadcast receiver via registerReceiver() method. In registered receiver I'll always check if user is on WiFi and if it is, download some bytes from server to check if user's country is now supported. And when became supported I'll unregister the receiver. My doubt in this idea is how long will programmatically registered broadcast receiver live? Maybe receiver will need to live for months. If user doesn't uninstall my application will receiver be receiving events all the time?

**2.** Register broadcast receiver in Android Manifest and when user request to be informed put boolean **shouldBeInformed** in SharedPreferences and always check this value before proceeding in broadcast receiver.

Do you have any ideas how to handle this problem elegantly and efficiently? C2DM is not suitable solution at this momemnt.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to implement feature in my Android application which will allow user to receive notification when their country is supported in my application and I have some doubts how to implement this feature.

Usually, "supported in my application" would imply an update to that application.

> User's country is always first and if it's not supported there is a button where he can click and request to be informed when his country become supported.

Save the country in `SharedPreferences`. On first launch after each update to the application, see if the country is on the supported list, and pop up a "hey! it's now supported!" dialog. Or, in a pinch, register for `ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED`, and if it was your package that was replaced, see if you support the country and put a `Notification` in the status bar.

> When user click on a button I'll register network state changed broadcast receiver via registerReceiver() method.

Why?

> In registered receiver I'll always check if user is on WiFi and if it is, download some bytes from server to check if user's country is now supported.

You do not need a `BroadcastReceiver` for this. Whenever you decide to check for updates (e.g., once per day via `AlarmManager`), you can check to see if the device is on WiFi. I am not quite certain why you care about WiFi or not, and I have no idea what this has to do with updating your application (typically handled by the Android Market).

> And when became supported I'll unregister the receiver.

It will have been unregistered a long time ago.

> My doubt in this idea is how long will programmatically registered broadcast receiver live? Maybe receiver will need to live for months.

It will live for however long the user has the activity on the screen. You need to unregister the receiver before your activity is paused. Even if you intentionally leak the receiver after the activity is destroyed -- which is a bad idea -- it will live for minutes, until Android terminates the process.

> Register broadcast receiver in Android Manifest and when user request to be informed put boolean shouldBeInformed in SharedPreferences and always check this value before proceeding in broadcast receiver.

Why?

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare, publishing new version on Android market is not needed when adding/removing country support. I always download the latest data when application starts. Of course, there is local caching mechanism on some level, but this is not the issue here. "Country is supported" means that the user will now have access to some new data that are related with his country.

Comment: @a.ilic: "I always download the latest data when application starts." -- then check to see if the country is supported when you download the data. If you want to let the user know when an update to the data is available, use `AlarmManager` and an `IntentService` to check once per day (or whatever frequency you deem appropriate).

Comment: My idea was to notify user even if he's not using my application, but it's installed on the phone. Thanks, I'll check `AlarmManager` and `IntentService`.